# How can I instantiate scala.swing.event.MousePressed?

Tags: swing, scala

How can I instantiate scala.swing.event.MousePressed? I tried the below but it complains about the constructor. The declaration of MousePressed says something about a Component peer... but I'm not sure how to include it.

```
import scala.swing.event.MousePressed
import java.awt.Point

object TypeIssue {
 val c = new Label()
 val test = new MousePressed(c, new Point(0,0), 0, 0, 1, false)
}
```

Error is:
overloaded method constructor MousePressed with alternatives:   (e: java.awt.event.MouseEvent)scala.swing.event.MousePressed    (source: scala.swing.Component,point: java.awt.Point,modifiers: scala.swing.event.Key.Modifiers,clicks: Int,triggersPopup: Boolean)(peer: java.awt.event.MouseEvent)scala.swing.event.MousePressed  cannot be applied to (scala.swing.Label, java.awt.Point, Int, Int, Int, Boolean)

Comment: possibly, related answer from Java world    [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900400/generate-event-swing]

Comment: MousePressed is a case class. You should read up on that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val test = 
  new MousePressed(new java.awt.event.MouseEvent(c.peer, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false))
```

We need the `new` before MousePressed because we're using the case class's auxiliary constructor (although why this should be necessary has never been explained).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
import scala.swing.event.MousePressed
import java.awt.Point
import scala.swing.Label

object TypeIssue {
 val c = new Label()
 val test = MousePressed(c, new Point(0,0), 0, 0, false)(new java.awt.event.MouseEvent(c.peer, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false))
}
```